# Cannot enter Formula-like string in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enter a formula-like string using VBA. Here it is:

```
=CONCATENER("Projet: ";'System Menu'!D5)
```

I'm trying to enter this in a cell with the following instruction:

```
   cellulevalue = "=" & cellulevalue
   rngLink.value = cellulevalue
```

Where `cellulevalue` contains `CONCATENER("Projet: ";'System Menu'!D5)` at first.

I'm expecting the cell's value to become `=CONCATENER("Projet: ";'System Menu'!D5)`, which is a completely valid instruction to put in a cell. If I use VBA to put it in the cell as shown, I get an Application or object error, but if I `debug.print` it instead and `paste` it right out of the `immediate window`, it works like a charm.

If anyone is curious, it is the Concatenate function in French. The output would be

```
Projet: [Whatever is in 'System Menu'!D5]
```

How can I enter the formula and get it to work?

Comment: vba is very us-English centric.  Change the `.Value` to `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: Wow that was easy! It works. If you want to answer with that I would accept.

Comment: Alternatively you could try writing the formula in English when inserting it with VBA

Comment: OT: I wouldn't suggest using local, I think it's better to write it in the original language -english- in the vba, excel will translate in your sheet if you write it by VBA.

Comment: @Sgdva I agree completely, however this is treating cells that are entered by the user, and they know the French formulas. I didn't write that myself, it's taken from a cell in another workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Within VBA, you have to use English formula descriptions.

```
rngLink.value = "=CONCATENATE(""Projet: "",'System Menu'!D5)"
```

should work.

Edit: 
You can also work with your local language formulas. @ScottCraner has suggested the following:

```
rngLink.FormulaLocal "=CONCATENER(""Projet: "", 'System Menu'!D5)"
```

which seems to work. Very useful, thanks for that! (I'm using a German Excel version and will probably be able to use this in the future ;)